# Elasticsearch date field: epoch millis input, string output?

Tags: elasticsearch

Steps:
1. Define a date field in a mapping.
2. Insert a epoch millisecond (long) value into that field.

Can elastic search returns a string value (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS) of that field for a search?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the date-format documentation of ElasticSearch, it will always accept a milliseconds-since-epoch input next to input in the format given by the format, and it will produce a String output using the (first) format given. If you don't provide a format, then the "date_optional_time" format will be used (yyyy-MM-dd’T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ).

If the time zone in there is a problem for you, you'd need to give ElasticSearch your intended format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code to hand, but in my testing I believe I managed to do the following:

I used the date formatter on the field and the query fields definition to do this:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1?fields=title,date_field.date_time'`

using the date formats specified here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/

If you want a full document returned, this may be onerous. In which case is it possible to use an alias 'view' mapping to get the result to return differently from your primary mapping? Possibly this has become a half-answer.